Hadoop Installation, Error: getSubject is supported only if a security manager is allowed
I tried to install Hadoop on my macOS Ventura but has been failed several times. I tried download the lower versions of hadoop as well but no luck so far.
Tried Hadoop Versions: 3.4.0 and 3.3.6
Java Version: java 23
Error Message i am getting while running hdfs namenode -format is:

Exiting with status 1: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getSubject is supported only if a security manager is allowed

Similary, after when i run start-all.sh:
Starting namenodes
Starting namenodes on [Sumans-MacBook-Pro.local]
Starting datanodes
localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of datanode process 3556
2024-09-23 16:10:29,438 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getSubject is supported only if a security manager is allowed
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.getSubject(Subject.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:577)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf.run(GetConf.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf.main(GetConf.java:361)
Starting resourcemanagers on []
Starting nodemanagers
localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of nodemanager process 3966

Configuration i tried are as follows:
core-site.xml
<configuration>
  <property>
      <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
      <value>/Users/sumanbhattarai/hdfs/tmp/</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>

hdfs-site.xml
<configuration>
  <property>
      <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
      <value>/Users/sumanbhattarai/hdfs/namenode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
      <value>/Users/sumanbhattarai/hdfs/datanode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>

mapred-site.xml
<configuration> 
  <property> 
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name> 
    <value>yarn</value> 
  </property> 
</configuration>

yarn-site.xml
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
    <value>0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist</name>   
    <value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,CLASSPATH_PERPEND_DISTCACHE,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME</value>
  </property>
</configuration>


There is an issue tracking this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-19212
The workaround (to run with -Djava.security.manager=allow) will go away once the Security Manager is permanent disabled, as proposed in JEP 486.

Spark only works with Java 8, 11 and 17 at the time of writing this answer. Consider downgrading from Java 23 that you are using now to one of the versions specified.
I recommend version 11 as the most stable one
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java11?er=221886

Java 23 introduced SecurityManager checks
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/23/security/migrating-deprecated-removal-methods-subject-getsubject-and-subject-doas-subject-current-and-subje.html
Hadoop does not support Java above version 11. Please downgrade and try again, making sure to configure other prerequisites.
Otherwise, you could also setup Hadoop in Docker, where the Java environment is pre configured.
https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/hadoop
