Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getSubject is supported only if a security manager is allowed
env: Windows + idea + maven + scala frame
i am studying how to use spark and just trying to run code as follow...
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object wordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("WordCount")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

    val fileRDD = sc.textFile("datas/words")

    val wordRDD = fileRDD.flatMap(_.split(" "))

    val word2OneRDD = wordRDD.map((_,1))

    val word2CountRDD = word2OneRDD.reduceByKey(_ + _)

    word2CountRDD.foreach(println)

    val collect = word2CountRDD.collect().toBuffer
    collect.foreach(println)

    word2CountRDD.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("datas/words/result")

    println("save to datas/words/result")

    sc.stop()

    println("done")
  }
}

and here is the pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

i guess the problem cause by hadoop configured by maven on windows but can't deal with it

downgrading java to 11 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79016199/hadoop-installation-error-getsubject-is-supported-only-if-a-security-manager-i/79167032#79167032

Thanks for sharing code. You forgot to share your stacktrace
